# Entity Framework EDMX Diagram table missing properties after update

Tags: entity-framework

I'm maintaining an asp.Net MVC 3 web application using Entity Framework 4.1 Database first approach. I have had to add two new properties to one of the tables in the database.

I then right clicked on the EDMX diagram and choose 'Update Model from Database' within the context menu, like so:

[image]

This works without any problems, but the two new fields aren't added to the expected table. However, when I open the EDMX file in XML format, I can see the two new fields listed, like so:

```
<EntityType Name="Shift">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="shiftID" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="shiftID" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
      //Two new fields below 
      <Property Name="shiftTitleGradeID" Type="int" />
      <Property Name="shiftTitleSubID" Type="int" />
</EntityType>
```

Can anyone advise me on how to get the two new fields into my EDMX diagram and not just the XML file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed. I had to delete all references to the new properties in the XML file. Then recreate the update model from database procedure, this time ensuring the two checkboxes where ticked, Pluralize or singularize generated object names, and, Include foreign key columns in the model (I thought I had these ticked the first time, but I didn't).

This fixed my problem.